# Stop spammers from relaying via sendmail?

Tags: linux, sendmail

For the life of me I cannot figure out how spammers are sendmail mail through my server with relaying off.  I'm running Sendmail 8.14.7 on Slackware Linux 14.1.  The spammers have not figured out a user's password and are therefore logging in first via SASL with AUTH LOGIN or I would see that in the log.

Heres an example from my logs, a spammer/bot from 182.234.55.47, off the top of someones head what would allow this?  Any IP randomly in the world can do this, yet when I try it sendmail says "relaying denied...".  I could not be more lost.  I firewall them but it happens again an hour later from a different IP.

```
Feb 23 12:18:44 server sendmail[28315]: t1NHIIgY028315: <-- MAIL FROM: <re>
Feb 23 12:18:44 server sendmail[28315]: t1NHIIgY028315: --- 250 2.1.0 <re>... Sender ok
Feb 23 12:18:45 server sendmail[28315]: t1NHIIgY028315: <-- RCPT TO: <htucker566@gmail.com>
Feb 23 12:18:45 server sendmail[28315]: t1NHIIgY028315: --- 250 2.1.5 <htunhtunnaing.goldpot@gmail.com>... Recipient ok
Feb 23 12:18:47 server sendmail[28315]: t1NHIIgY028315: <-- DATA
Feb 23 12:18:47 server sendmail[28315]: t1NHIIgY028315: --- 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
Feb 23 12:18:48 server sendmail[28315]: t1NHIIgY028315: from=<re>, size=496, class=0, nrcpts=5, msgid=<B3BE0AC12425C02A1FB8C9201EE5CB9E@jyvicegy>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=host-47.55-234-182.cable.dynamic.kbtelecom.net [182.234.55.47]
Feb 23 12:18:48 central sendmail[28315]: t1NHIIgY028315: --- 250 2.0.0 t1NHIIgY028315 Message accepted for delivery
```

Comment: Is it possible that they have found a way to abuse something else running on the server (such as a web site script that is used to send mail, or a contact form, for example) to make it send outgoing mail?  Or perhaps they've found a vulnerablilty (such as the shellshock), that gives them remote execution ability, and they're exploiting that.  If you do `netstat -an | grep 182.234.55.47` do you see connections from this IP to your server?  If so, what port are they connecting on and what service are they connecting to?

Comment: yes, I thought of all this.  it seems like they might be submitting it locally somehow.  But everytime I see them spamming I do a netstat and sure enough the IP is there connected to my port 25 "tcp        0      0 My.Server.Ip.:25       182.234.55.47:5541   ESTABLISHED".  They would not have to connect to port 25 if they were spamming through a wordpress plugin hole.  And they are not exploiting anything or I would see strange characters in the sendmail logging wouldn't I?  I just see a clean connection, mail, and disconnect.

Comment: Besides even the sendmail log there says "relay=host-47.55-234-182.cable.dynamic.kbtelecom.net [182.234.55.47]", does that not mean the message originally came from 182.234.55.47?  And I do not see the IP at the time (182.234.55.47) in my apache logs at all.

Comment: OK.  In that case, it sounds like you're fairly sure that they are connecting to your server on port 25 and somehow either bypassing the SMTP authentication, or relaying the message through your SMTP server somehow.  Have you tried to see if you can repeat the same thing?  What happens if you connect to your server from some other host on port 25 (using telnet, for example), and start an SMTP session, and try doing the same thing that they're doing?

Comment: yes, I tried that, I get "Relaying denied, proper authentication required" which is why its so strange.  Its impossible yet happening.

Comment: If you're sure that your mail server is not acting as an open relay, then they must be by-passing the SMTP authentication somehow.  How about running `tcpdump` to capture everything to/from 182.234.55.47 to see exactly what they are doing and how they are doing it?

Comment: I think I got it, they are authenticating elsewhere but I have no idea how.  If there is no AUTH LOGIN or whatever in the port 25 transaction shown above I have no idea how they can AUTH elsewhere first.

Comment: It looks like part of the SMTP session is missing from the transaction copied above.  I don't even see `HELO` or `EHLO` in the transaction copied above.  When you connect from a different host to your server on port 25, do you see AUTH LOGIN after the `EHLO` exchange?  Capturing the traffic to/from 182.234.55.47  using tcpdump might get to the bottom of this fast.

Comment: See https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/mail/test-smtp-auth-telnet for information on how to manually test if your server is supporting SMTP authentication.  If so, this may be how they are sending these messages through.